# Adding multiple links in VBA

Tags: vba

When I try and create both of the files as links within the outlook email, only one of the files shows up as a link. How can I resolve this so both will show up as links.

```
Set omail = CreateItem(olMailItem)
```

With omail

```
.Subject = "Key Report"
.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
.HTMLBody = "<a href ='" & fileL & "'>Key Report</a>"
.HTMLBody = "<a href ='" & fileSat & "'>Key Report Saturday</a>"
.To = abc@yah.com       
.Display

End With
```

Comment: Editor, this post was off-topic, because it is not reproductible in reference to its type of error. So this question didn't need an edit, but a flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the HTMLBody, when you should concatenate them.

```
Set omail = CreateItem(olMailItem)

With omail
  .Subject = "Key Report"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
  .HTMLBody = "<a href ='" & fileL & "'>Key Report</a>" & _ 
              "<a href ='" & fileSat & "'>Key Report Saturday</a>"
  .To = abc@yah.com       
  .Display
End With
```