# VBA parsing of href

Tags: vba, excel

I've [googled](https://www.google.gr/search?q=parse%20HTML%20vba&rlz=1C1CHFX_enGR573GR573&oq=parse%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j0l4.3280j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) and also searched many posts on Stack some of them interesting for this[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535180/pulling-a-table-out-of-a-mess-of-html-w-vba-excel),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916900/adding-multiple-links-in-vba),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443773/extracting-xml-attribute-using-vba?rq=1),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188999/query-and-parse-xml-attribute-value-into-xls-using-vba?lq=1)

I'll show you what i am after. I picked [a random site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_%28B%29) and copied a few lines (from 155 to 174)

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._I" title="B.A.C. I" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. I</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._II" title="B.A.C. II" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. II</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._III" title="B.A.C. III" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. III</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._IV" title="B.A.C. IV" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. IV</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._V" title="B.A.C. V" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. V</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VI" title="B.A.C. VI" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VI</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII" title="B.A.C. VII" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII_Mk.2" title="B.A.C. VII Mk.2" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII Mk.2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII_Planette" title="B.A.C. VII Planette" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII Planette</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VIII" title="B.A.C. VIII" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VIII</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VIII_Bat-Boat" title="B.A.C. VIII Bat-Boat" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VIII Bat-Boat</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._IX" title="B.A.C. IX" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. IX</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Cupid" title="B.A.C. Cupid" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Cupid</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Drone" title="B.A.C. Drone" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Drone</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Super_Drone" title="B.A.C. Super Drone" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Super Drone</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Swallow_2" title="B.A. Swallow 2" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Swallow 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Eagle_2" title="B.A. Eagle 2" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Eagle 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Double_Eagle" title="B.A. Double Eagle" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Double Eagle</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to find one value between the HTML tags for example `B.A.C. VII` and then use VBA to actually go in to the link `href` of the line item which holds `B.A.C. VII`. After i have navigated there i need to get the resulting URL in a String. Keep in mind that i need highly prefer binding if possible. I tried to write a loop but with no success...

Dear Ron

Debugger stops on the first line andd...
It giving me `Run-time error '424'` however we have an object qualifier everywhere...

[image]

**thanks for watching my question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop works for me.

```
Sub test()
' open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = "http://www.xyz.com"

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

' Find the desired url and click
Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each itm In Results
    If itm.outerhtml = "B.A.C. VII" Then
        itm.Click

        Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at the question in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382602/pasting-urls-that-have-been-scraped-from-a-webpage) to see how to create and assign your IE object with content. Your error arises because the IE object in your macro has neither been defined nor had any content added to it. The question is the first one that popped up using the search term 'vba scraping webpages'.

Comment: It's the IE that needs to be defined? I thing the `Results` are. Coming back to you once i check this thread. Thanks

Comment: Added an up front piece to my answer to open and navigate IE