# VBA HTML Tag Hierarchy

Tags: html, vba, excel

A simple question. I am trying to write a procedure to parse the HTML of [this Site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_%28B%29)

A part of the source code (lines 154 to 174) that is sufficient for a paradigm is:

```
<p>(British Aircraft Company)</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._I" title="B.A.C. I" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. I</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._II" title="B.A.C. II" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. II</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._III" title="B.A.C. III" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. III</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._IV" title="B.A.C. IV" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. IV</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._V" title="B.A.C. V" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. V</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VI" title="B.A.C. VI" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VI</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII" title="B.A.C. VII" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII_Mk.2" title="B.A.C. VII Mk.2" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII Mk.2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VII_Planette" title="B.A.C. VII Planette" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VII Planette</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VIII" title="B.A.C. VIII" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VIII</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._VIII_Bat-Boat" title="B.A.C. VIII Bat-Boat" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. VIII Bat-Boat</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._IX" title="B.A.C. IX" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. IX</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Cupid" title="B.A.C. Cupid" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Cupid</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Drone" title="B.A.C. Drone" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Drone</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A.C._Super_Drone" title="B.A.C. Super Drone" class="mw-redirect">B.A.C. Super Drone</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Swallow_2" title="B.A. Swallow 2" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Swallow 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Eagle_2" title="B.A. Eagle 2" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Eagle 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/B.A._Double_Eagle" title="B.A. Double Eagle" class="mw-redirect">B.A. Double Eagle</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am in the process of trying to engineer something out. So i can get to the `<p> HTML Tag` but i cannot tap on the list items to loop out what i want because they are further enclosed between the `<ul></ul> tags`. What would be your next steps?

```
Sub ICE()

Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("p")

For Each itm In Results
    If itm.innerHTML = "(British Aircraft Company)" Then




    End If
Next itm

End Sub
```

For a more concise picture this stage of my study is based on the answer at [VBA parsing of href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842608/vba-parsing-of-href) provided by [ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604372/ron)

Recomendation by user [Doug Glancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293078/doug-glancy)

--> It might be helpful to mention the `desired results.`

What i want is to have the capability to make VBA to 'click' on runtime the href of my preference since it is an actual link. I am studying code from ron on that which is (and can be seen in the [previous example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842608/vba-parsing-of-href)):

```
If itm.outerhtml = "B.A.C. VII" Then
        itm.Click

        Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Exit For
 End If
```

...here outerHTML is being used however the nucleus of my effort is the loop and the logical operator

---

I wrote this piece of code however it does not work

```
Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("p")

For Each itm In Results
    If itm.innerHTML = "(British Aircraft Company)" Then
        Set Results2 = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("ul")
        For Each itm2 In Results2
            If itm2.innerHTML = "B.A.C. V" Then
                MsgBox itm2.innerHTML
            End If

        Next itm2
    End If
Next itm
```

Comment: It might be helpful to mention your desired results.

Comment: Adding now the desired results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will list out the aircraft under the p tag with British Aircraft Company

```
Sub GetAircraft()

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hUls As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim hUl As MSHTML.HTMLListElement
    Dim hLi As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement

    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    xHttp.Open "GET", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_%28B%29"
    xHttp.send

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until xHttp.readyState = 4

    Set hDoc = New HTMLDocument
    hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText
    Set hUls = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("ul")

    'Go through all the <ul> tags
    For Each hUl In hUls
        'Only if previous tag is something
        If Not hUl.PreviousSibling Is Nothing Then
            'Only if previous tag is <p>
            If TypeName(hUl.PreviousSibling) = "HTMLParaElement" Then
                'Only if previous paragraph is specified text
                If hUl.PreviousSibling.innerText = "(British Aircraft Company)" Then
                    'loop through the <li> and print them out
                    For Each hLi In hUl.Children
                        Debug.Print hLi.innerText
                    Next hLi
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next hUl

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW just a question why do you use GET instead of POST? it just struck me.

Comment: isn't is safer with POST?

Comment: anyways i'll check GET out :P This is a perfect answer i will learn with dilligence!!! THANK YOU SIR

Comment: I'm not an HTML expert (not even close), so I can't speak knowledgeably about GET v POST. I use GET by default and only use POST if I have a reason, like potential security issues.