# VBA - Trying to extract information from webpage through HTML but can't return values inside {{ }}

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to return some data from a webpage into Excel using VBA. The website in question is linked below:

http://thecise.com/market/securities/3160

I want to extract the data from the "Category:" listing, which in this case reads "Hedge Fund".

I've been using some code put together previously from the following thread: [VBA HTML Tag Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857941/vba-html-tag-hierarchy), which in its current form does pull down all the information within the HTML lists, but doesn't work for the "Category:" heading.

I'm not very experienced with HTML, but the difference appears to be that the HTML code for this heading includes some reference value contained within {{ }}, rather than the text "Hedge Fund" as with the other list items.

```
<li>
    <span>Category:</span>
    <span>{{security.s_cmpycat}}</span
</li>
```

Is there a way that I can adjust the code below to return the value presented on the website, rather than the raw HTML code? (i.e. return the value "Hedge Fund" rather than "{{security.s_cmpycat}}" I tried using the "From Web" data extract tool from Excel too but that didn't work either.

I realise that the code below lists all the list values rather than just the one above, but I hadn't tailored it further until I could figure out how to return the right value.

VBA Code:

```
Sub GetCISEDAta()

Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim hUls As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim hUl As MSHTML.HTMLListElement
Dim hLi As MSHTML.HTMLLIElement

Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
xHttp.Open "GET", "http://thecise.com/market/securities/3160"
xHttp.send

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until xHttp.readyState = 4

Set hDoc = New HTMLDocument
hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText
Set hUls = hDoc.getElementsByTagName("ul")

For Each hUl In hUls
        For Each hLi In hUl.Children
               Debug.Print hLi.innerText
        Next hLi
Next hUl

End Sub
```

HTML Code Section:

```
            <div class="row">

                <div class="security-listing-col security-listing-registration-data">
                    <ul class="dl-list list-unstyled">
                        <li>
                            <span>ISIN:</span>
                            <span>GG00B247XG70</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Date Listed:</span>
                            <span>28-09-2007</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Domicile:</span>
                            <span>Guernsey</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Sponsor:</span>
                            <span><a href="/members/current-members/2721">Vistra Fund Services (Guernsey) Ltd</a></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span>Category:</span>
                            <span>{{security.s_cmpycat}}</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="security-listing-col security-listing-col-hidemd">
                    <div class="hr mb-20"></div>
                </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: look at the answer and comments here, it is very similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126580/how-to-run-website-forms-in-excel-without-having-to-use-sendkeys

Comment: The URL you should look for geting details is : http://www.thecise.com/umbraco/surface/proxyapi/getsecuritydetails?id=3160 it will return a JSON data set , and then you need to parse it.

Comment: Ah that's brilliant! Thanks very much!